# Performing a put or patch request with token

Tags: c#, http, httprequest

I've got a chunk of code:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(String.Format("{0}:{1}", "Username", "password"))));

var method = new HttpMethod("PATCH");

var reqmsg = new HttpRequestMessage(method, uri)
{
    Content = new StringContent(request, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
};

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(reqmsg);
```

This works fine using Basic authentication. I want to use a token though, and if I change the Authorization to use a webtoken:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Token", WebToken);
```

I now get a 403 Forbidden error. If I'm doing a Post or a Get, the token works, but not for Patch or Put. I'm guessing the token is somehow being stripped off. is there a way around this?

Comment: You can determine whether the token is being stripped off or not by trying to do this with a REST client (like the extensions for Chrome/Firefox) or by looking at the request with Fiddler. This might be an issue in the configuration of the server and not your code

Comment: PATCH has been tested successfully through a REST framework, so it doesn't look like server setup.

Answer (score -2):

You're getting a 403 error because the encoding is incorrect.
-facepalm-
You're using UTF8 while the default is ANCI...  Doesn't make sense.

Comment: The encoding has absolutely nothing to do with invalid credentials. Besides, there's no such thing as "ANCI".
Please delete this.